# How to change the div after submit the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

How to change the background of div of form and result after submit the form? I want to change the background of form and result from image to color.

How to do this? I'm trying this solution that I found, but it's not working, http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YL6Da/

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oxpy4bmx/3/)

```
<form action="" method="post" name="locator">
    <div class="locator-div">
        <select name="locator1_list" id="filterby">
            <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <span class="or">or</span>
    <div class="locator-div">
        <select name="locator1_list" id="filterby">
            <option name="default" class="filter_by" value="Select by">Select by</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="List all locations" class="location-submit">
</form>

<div class="records"><div><span class="icons-tabbed-store icon-icon-stores"> Location 1</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();
    var bool = false;
    
    if (bool) {
        $("form").addClass("success");
        $(".records").addClass("error");
    } else {
        $("form").addClass("error");
        $(".records").addClass("success");
    }
});
```

copy that css classes and add  background-image:none

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, I got it right but anyway.

If you need to change the style of any element, all what you need to do is using this jQuery css method, For example:-

```
$("#message").css("background-color","green")
```

Or you can use AddClass method, and that's what you did on fiddle

Why it's not working, that because you wrote inline style in the textarea

```
style="color: white; background-color: grey; display: none
```

And the inline style has highest priority, so it will replace/overwrite any style written in external css class like ".success"

So it's your choice either to work with classes and use AddClass / removeClass methods, and don't write style in the tag itself

OR

Use inline style and use css method to update that

Answer (score 0):

You want to do Synch or Asynch? If Asynch, you need to use AJAX:

```
$("#id-of-form").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$.ajax({
    url: 'url-of-form',
    type: 'post',
    success: function (response)
    {
        var bool = false;

        if (bool) {
            $("#message").fadeIn("slow").removeAttr("style").addClass("success").text("Successful!");
        } else {
            $("#message").fadeIn("slow").removeAttr("style").addClass("error").text("Failed");
        }
    }
}); 
});
```

Basically what you are doing here is attaching a function to the submit event and resubmiting it by Ajax, thus, making a Asynch call.

If you want Synch, you need to use PHP or whatever language you are using.

Comment: sorry for late reply. But I'm not using ajax

Comment: When you submit a form, it sends a request to the action you provided, the code you got attach itself and is activated before the request is sent, it will never work. You need to use your server side language, what's yours?

Comment: When submitting a form, I'm using the typical `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`

Comment: Ok so you want something like
`<form action="" method="post" name="locator" class="<?php echo isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['your-var-name'] == 'something' ? 'success' : 'error' ?>">`

It is called a ternary operator, basically is a IF condition shorthanded...